# Reverse nearest neighbor

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour

My questions is: What is the "real" difference between Reverse nearest neighbor(RNN) and Nearest neighbor(NN) queries? In my opinion, these two should return same result.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The definition given by

[Papadias D., Tao Y. (2009) Reverse Nearest Neighbor Query. In: LIU L., ÖZSU M.T. (eds) Encyclopedia of Database Systems. Springer, Boston, MA](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-39940-9_318)

states that

> Given a multi-dimensional dataset $P$ and a point $q$, a reverse nearest neighbor (RNN) query retrieves all the points $p\in{P}$ that have $q$ as their nearest neighbor.

As a simple example, consider the 1D point set $P=[a,b,c]=[0,2,3]$. Then we have
\begin{align}
\mathrm{NN}(a) &= b \\
\mathrm{NN}(b) &= c \\
\mathrm{NN}(c) &= b
\end{align}
So
\begin{align}
\mathrm{RNN}(a) &= \emptyset \\
\mathrm{RNN}(b) &= \{a,c\} \\
\mathrm{RNN}(c) &= b
\end{align}
Does this help?

Comment: I got the logic, Exactly what i was looking for simple yet informative. Thank you!

Comment: @GeoMatt22 The reverse nearest neighbour relation is not a symmetric relation.

Comment: Could you include a full reference in case the link goes dead in the future?

Comment: @RichardHardy done.